# Code compiles correctly but the image doesn't show up

Tags: c++

I'm trying to test and animate some Clifford attractors
Seen here:
http://paulbourke.net/fractals/clifford/

I tried compiling the code taken from here.
http://paulbourke.net/fractals/clifford/paul_richards/main.cpp
The code compiles but no image file is generated.

I'm using:
Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.38.0
Commit: 3db7e09f3b61f915d03bbfa58e258d6eee843f35
Date: 2019-09-03T21:51:09.716Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-60-generic snap

```
/*
        xn+1 = sin(a yn) + c cos(a xn)
        yn+1 = sin(b xn) + d cos(b yn)
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Change params only in this block
namespace {
    const int width = 1600;
    const int height = 1200;
    const int frames = 10000;
    const int iters = 10000;
    const int skipIters = 10;

    double sensitivity = 0.02;

    const double minX = -4.0;
    const double minY = minX * height / width;

    const double maxX = 4.0;
    const double maxY = maxX * height / width;

    const double minA = acos( 1.6 / 2.0 );
    const double maxA = acos( 1.3 / 2.0 );

    const double minB = acos( -0.6 / 2.0 );
    const double maxB = acos( 1.7 / 2.0 );

    const double minC = acos( -1.2 / 2.0 );
    const double maxC = acos( 0.5 / 2.0 );

    const double minD = acos( 1.6 / 2.0 );
    const double maxD = acos( 1.4 / 2.0 );
};




class Color {
    public:

    double r, g, b;

    Color(const double &red = 0, const double &green = 0, const double &blue = 0) : r(red), g(green), b(blue) {
    }

    Color& operator+=(const Color &rhs) {
        r += rhs.r;
        g += rhs.g;
        b += rhs.b;
        return *this;
    }

    static Color createHue( double h ) {
        h *= 6.0;
        int hi = static_cast<int>( h );
        double hf = h - hi;


        switch( hi % 6 ) {
            case 0:
            return Color( 1.0 , hf, 0.0 );
            case 1:
            return Color( 1.0 - hf, 1.0, 0.0 );
            case 2:
            return Color( 0.0 , 1.0, hf );
            case 3:
            return Color( 0.0, 1.0 - hf, 1.0 );
            case 4:
            return Color( hf, 0.0, 1.0 );
            case 5:
            return Color( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 - hf );
        }

        return Color();
    }


    Color operator+(const Color &rhs) const {
        return Color(*this) += rhs;
    }


};

int main(void) {

    vector<Color> image( width * height );

    for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {

        const double p = static_cast<double>(i) / frames;
        const double a = cos( minA + p * (maxA - minA) ) * 2.0;
        const double b = cos( minB + p * (maxB - minB) ) * 2.0;
        const double c = cos( minC + p * (maxC - minC) ) * 2.0;
        const double d = cos( minD + p * (maxD - minD) ) * 2.0;

        const Color curCol = Color::createHue( p ); 

        double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;

        for (int j = 0; j < iters; j++) {

            double xn = sin(a * y) + c * cos(a * x);
            double yn = sin(b * x) + d * cos(b * y);
            x = xn;
            y = yn;

            if ( j < skipIters )
                continue;


            int xi = static_cast<int>( (x - minX) * width / (maxX - minX) );
            int yi = static_cast<int>( (y - minY) * height / (maxY - minY) );
            if ( xi >= 0 && xi < width &&
                 yi >= 0 && yi < height ) {

                 image[ xi + yi * width ] += curCol;

            }

        }
        clog << "\r" << i;

    }
    clog << "\n";

    cout
        << "P6\n"
        << width << " " << height << "\n"
        << "255\n";

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            Color &c = image[ x + y * width ];

            unsigned char r = static_cast<unsigned char>( (1.0 - exp( -sensitivity * c.r )) * 255.0 );
            unsigned char g = static_cast<unsigned char>( (1.0 - exp( -sensitivity * c.g )) * 255.0 );
            unsigned char b = static_cast<unsigned char>( (1.0 - exp( -sensitivity * c.b )) * 255.0 );

            cout << r << g << b;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just using it incorrectly? It outputs a PPM files contents to `cout`, run it from a command line outputting the application output to a file, then view it, either with a PPM viewer or by converting to PNG first. ([This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2xL.jpg) is the output I got with the parameters in the code you provided)

Comment: The console app creates a dat file, you should be seeing that in the window. A `app.exe >> file.dat` and you can send it to a file. I looked a little on the site but don't see a mention of a viewer. But I'm sure it is there.

Comment: This question needs to be rewritten. Although it's obvious to me what it's trying to do, it's not going to be obvious to most people. This is obviously trying to create a ppm file. Where is that explained in this question? Nowhere. And if what's happening here is that you've copied the original code from one of the cited links, but don't understand it, perhaps it's better to focus learning C++ fundamentals first, before attempting to copy and hack random C++ code found on the Internet. P.S. Read the ppm spec and then look at the created file. The problem should be obvious.

Comment: Need thing about code that compiles. It can still fail to work. Happens all the time.